# IntelliJ standard dialog controls and chinese symbols

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, fonts, character-encoding

How to make IntelliJ IDEA properly show chinese symbols in standard dialog controls I wonder?

[I want to have chinese symbols in the configuration name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P5sy.png)

[This is how it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXjUj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the appearance font:

[image: font]

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. But I use DialogInput font instead.